# How can i edit the polygon that i import from file with edit control?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

i using the react leaflet and editcontrol.Th ploiblem is i imported the geojson file that i created from editcontrol but i cant edit anything on my lastest polygon

```
<MapContainer ref={mapRef} center={mapCenter} zoom={mapZoom} style={{ zIndex: 1 }} className="w-full h-screen">
          <ImageOverlay bounds={bounds} url={imageOverlayUrl} />
          <FeatureGroup>
            {adminMode ? (
              <EditControl
                position="topright"
                onCreated={onCreated}
                draw={{
                  rectangle: false,
                }}
              />
            ) : null}
          </FeatureGroup>
          {geoJsonData && (
            <GeoJSON
              data={geoJsonData}
              style={renderGeoJSONStyle}
              onEachFeature={renderGeoJSONOnEachFeature}
            />

          )}
        </MapContainer>
```

```
  const importGeoJson = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
        try {
          const importedData = JSON.parse(e.target?.result as string);
          setImportedData(importedData.features || []);
          setGeoJsonData(importedData);
          setImageOverlayUrl(importedData.imageOverlayUrl)
          console.log("GeoJSON import successful!"); // Log success message
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
        }
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  };
```

i need to edit the polygon coordinates i import from gejson file with react leaflet edit control

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.